# unable receive touch events of UIButton created pragrammatically

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I created a custom UIButton class. On button click I need to display(animate) three buttons, for that I created three button(btn1,btn2,btn3) programmatically I added all these three buttons inside stackView and given constraints to stackView and kept this stackView inside another containerView(for background colour for buttons) and given constraints programmatically. The problem is I am able to display and animate the container View. But unable to receive touch action of buttons inside of stackview I added target for button but still not able to receive action any problem in my code

```
class ReactionButton : UIButton
 {
    lazy var btnsMainView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray5
        view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.height/2
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.isHidden = true
        return view
    }()
    var btn1 : UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped1), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn }()
    var btn2 = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
    var btn3 = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    
    var leftMainViewAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint?
    var bottomMainViewAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint?
    var widthMainViewAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint?
    var heightMainViewAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
         addStackView()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        addStackView()
        btn2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped1), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        btnsMainView.isHidden = false
        bottomMainViewAnchor?.constant = -30
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
    }
    
    func addStackView()
    {
        
        self.addSubview(btnsMainView)
        btnsMainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        leftMainViewAnchor = btnsMainView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0)
        leftMainViewAnchor?.isActive = true
        widthMainViewAnchor = btnsMainView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        widthMainViewAnchor?.isActive = true
        heightMainViewAnchor = btnsMainView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        heightMainViewAnchor?.isActive = true
        bottomMainViewAnchor = btnsMainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        bottomMainViewAnchor?.isActive = true
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [btn1 , btn2,btn3])
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 2.0
        //stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        btnsMainView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btnsMainView.addSubview(stackView)
      
        //stackView Constraints
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnsMainView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnsMainView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnsMainView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnsMainView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender : UIButton)
    {

    }
    @objc func btnTapped1(_ sender : UIButton)
    {
        print("button tapped1")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an odd setup... I'd think it would be easier to manage as a custom `UIView`.

However, you can interact with your "dynamically displayed buttons" by adding this to your `ReactionButton` class:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // if btnsMainView is hidden, we've tapped on self
    if btnsMainView.isHidden {
        return self
    }
    // loop through subviews, checking hitTest until we find one
    for v in subviews.reversed() {
        let p = v.convert(point, from: self)
        let r = v.hitTest(p, with: event)
        if r != nil {
            return r
        }
    }
    // didn't tap on a subview, so return nil
    return nil
}
```